# How to make TDictionary do not free items ?

Tags: delphi

I use some TDictionary to improve searches speed. But I don't want it to clear my objects when I free it. Like TObjectList with property OwnsObjects=False, is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: `TDictionary` does not own objects, so it does not release them. That's what `TObjectDictionary` can do. Are you sure you're blaming the right class ?

Comment: TLama, you're right. My mistake.

Comment: I'll remove the question, 'cause it doesn't make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TDictionary<K,V>` does not own its members. `TObjectDictionary<K,V>` can optionally own keys, values, both or neither. This ownership is determined by the arguments you pass to the constructor.

If you are using `TDictionary<K,V>` and think that it is destroying its members, then you are mistaken.